# Add professional memberships section to CV

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs

This might not be relevant to everyone, but it would be nice if there was a section to add professional memberships to the CV, for example:

> IEEE, Computer Society, 2009-2009

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically include that in your educational achievements. Otherwise, yes a new section would be required.

**Edit** Also see related suggestion: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25294/build-your-own-cv